# Passing a textbox value to a class then binding the value across pages

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here. I am trying to pass along a textbox value across pages using a class.

I created a class page and in it created properties to use to bind textboxes.

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Masca
{
    public class loggedin
    {
        public string aliasname { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then in the code behind the main window I registered the new "logged" class I just created.
I then instantiated it and gave it a value of `FOO`

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace Masca
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : ModernWindow
    {
        public loggedin loggedin;

        public MainWindow(string Str_Value)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            loggedin = new loggedin { aliasname = "FOO" };
            this.DataContext = loggedin;
            username.Text = Str_Value;
```

I then added to all pages I wanted to show `FOO`:

```
this.DataContext = logged;
```

And then I bound the textboxes to the property "logged" e.g

```
<TextBox x:Name="username" Text="{Binding aliasname}" Margin="134,77,0,0" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="211" Height="19" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="11" />
```

Unfortunately the only page showing `FOO` is the page I instantiated it in, where I put:

```
loggedin = new loggedin { aliasname = "FOO" };
```

In theory you would expect `loggedin` to pass `foo` around the pages right? No such luck. Does anyone see where I'm going wrong? `Foo` is supposed to be the content of `Username.text`. So all the pages know who just logged in. That value was already passed from the login page to the Main window successfully using the winforms method.

Comment: What do your other "pages" look like? Are these separate Pages with no relationship to MainWindow.xaml? Where is your logic in MainWindow.xaml which makes a reference to the other page you expect your `loggedin` to be available in?

Comment: The Mainwindow acts as a frame for the other pages and accesses them through links. e.g <mui:Link DisplayName="Home" Source="/Pages/Home.xaml" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your class is not singleTon and it doesn't implement INotitfyPropertyChanged, Change your code little bit as follows

```
public class loggedin:INotitfyPropertyChanged
{
    private static loggedin instance=new loggedin ();
    public static loggedin Instance
    {
         get{return instance;}
    }
    private string alisa;
    public string aliasname 
    { 
      get
      {
          return alisa;
      } 
      set
      {
          alisa=value;
          RaisePropertyChanged("aliasname");

      } 
    }



    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string prop)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) 
        { 
          PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop)); 
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Then set the data context in all the xmal.cs as below, if your accessing any property also use the same way

```
DataContext=loggedin.Instance;
```

To access a property do the following way

```
loggedin.Instance.aliasname="Foo";
```

Comment: thanks for this. It almost works actually but for some reason the error log says the second "PropertyChanged" can only appear on the left hand side of += or -= and both "PropertyChangedEventArgs" and "PropertyChangedEventHandler" cant be found... am i missing something?

Comment: Offer, I wouldn't recommend making loggedin a singleton. It's not a good practice in this case, your `loggedin` instance should already be your data context in your child pages if it is setup correctly. Take a look at what I suggested. No offense Kumareshan.

Comment: Ya i missed to implement INotitfyPropertyChanged as below  
public class loggedin:INotitfyPropertyChanged and add the using System.ComponentModel;

Comment: OKAY! And we have a winner. Kumareshan much gratitude... You made staying up all night worth it. I have another question if it isnt too much trouble... Any clue on how i could make FOO the value of a textbox?

Comment: Nevermind. I just figured out it works with that too. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, well based on the comments you have provided, if you are navigating to separate pages from links on the page, you are effectively navigating away from `MainWindow.xaml`, thus breaking the data context. If MainWindow.xaml is truly a frame, you should have each new embedded page as a page User Control within MainWindow, User Controls then by default inherit their parent's `DataContext`. In your case this could then be cast as a `loggedin` and utilised.

I would also highly recommend using the [MVVM Light](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) framework by Laurent Bugnion. It's a fantastic framework for taking on the MVVM pattern and encourages and regulates the use of best practices. It's also not scary to get started with the basics. This walks through a quick [getting started sample](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/creating/) and [this article](http://jesseliberty.com/2011/01/04/wpfs-mvvm-light-toolkit-soup-to-nuts-part-i/) disects the hello world sample quite nicely (ignore that it says windows phone, this sample works the same for wpf).

It should also be noted that, your `loggedin` class also requires some changes if you wish to have `aliasname` update on your UI if it receives any data changes:

```
public class loggedin : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public string _aliasname = null;
        public string aliasname
        {
            get { return _aliasname; }
            set
            {
                _aliasname = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("aliasname");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

With MVVM Light however, you would actually only inherit `ViewModelBase` and call this single line in your setter: `RaisePropertyChanged(() => aliasname)` you wouldn't need all the other plumbing fluff such as the event and virtual method. Which mind you needs to be repeated for each view model you setup. Very repetitious.

Comment: :( apparently.. [CallerMemberName] could not be found.. you'd think there are higher forces working against me. Is there a using system I'm missing?

Comment: Remove that `[CallerMemberName]` part. I don't think it is necessary, ReSharper might have added that on me.

Comment: Thanks for the help Neal. I had to give him his credit though. His implementation did do what I asked after all. Although I've already downloaded MVVM lite and I'll definately use that method once my project has been reviewed. You taught me something.

Comment: No problem. Best of luck. Just using singleton (static) instances I don't think will be feasible long term, it's not the best way to share the data around. Hopefully you'll get time to investigate MVVM Light! :)